# Azure Devops: what does changed date mean? What kind of changes does it track?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, change-management

I am working in a change management team and I need to create a dashboard where I can see how many changes have been within an area path. I created a query with the field "changed date" however I do not know what does that track? Does it track if there is any change in the description? What I am interested in is that how many features have been moved to the next iteration path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Changed Date` tracks any changes made for work item (not just Description).
You could see it from `History` tab also, which you could open for work item using the following icon:

[image]

Comment: First of all thank you for the quick reply. Hm..that is what I thought. In that case that query is not useful for me. Any chance you know how to track or create a dashboard to track how many features have been moved to the next iteration path? Thank you!

Comment: You might wanna open a new question for that one @Kitti

Answer (score 0):

It tracks any change made to the work item.